# Taxonomy in multilingual site

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have developed a multilingual blog (two languages). Some of my articles are both languages.

I'm trying to do the following:

As you can see, this article is tagged with the 'Drupal Gardens' tag: (This is not my site. It's a blog with the functionality I would like to implement)

http://reyero.net/es/drupal/construyendo_sitios_web_multilingues_con_drupal_gardens

When you click on the taxonomy link, the next page is showing the articles with the 'Drupal Gardens' tag, but only in spanish.
http://reyero.net/es/taxonomy/term/85

Then, if you change the language to english http://reyero.net/taxonomy/term/85 is showing the articles with the 'Drupal Gardens' tag, but only in english.

How can I implement this functionality in my blog. reyero.net is not my site. It's a blog with the functionality I am searching for.

Comment: The question is how can I implement this functionality in my blog. reyero.net is not my site. It's a blog with the functionality  I am searching for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must activate the module `Taxonomy translation (i18n_taxonomy)` then go to `admin/structure/taxonomy/YOUR_TAXONOMY_NAME/edit` and select:

- Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated.

Add a term and select the language and click the button <kbd>Save and translate</kbd> in the next page click the link `add translation` and create the translation.

Then create a node with this term that you hace create and you will have this functionality in your site.

Comment: Taxonomy translation (submodule from i18n module) must be activated too.

Comment: @user2132478 I see that was an error, you have reason, I edit now

Comment: Hm, didn't know you could use the 'kbd'-tag around here too!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens there is a tag for a button? I think now that the kbd-tag is for keyboard input, but I don't sure.

Comment: I mean the HTML tag 'kbd' as you used for that 'Save and translate' in your answer ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I know, I use the kbd to simulate the button 'Save and translate', It this correct? Et je viens de vouz ecrire un email, merci pour votre aide ;-)